# Unable to get user field value on AfterProperties EventReceiver

Tags: event-receivers

I am not able to get user field on AfterProperties in EventReceiver. I am using ItemUpdating event as I want to compare old value and new value. But I am getting error while fetching user field using `properties.AfterProperties[fieldname]`.

```
 SPFieldUserValueCollection newValue = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(properties.Web.Site.RootWeb, Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties["fieldname"]));
```

In `newValue`I am getting -1;#i:0#,w|domain\user

Getting Id as -1

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the user from afterProperties hasn't been ensured yet and therefore doesn't have the right ID from the Users List (-1).

You could solve your Problem by calling

```
properties.Web.EnsureUser("claim|domain\user");
```

for every user before using it in SPFieldUserValueCollection.

If you just need the login name you can use a normal SPFieldLookupValueCollection instead of SPFieldUserValueCollection.

Example:

```
 SPFieldLookupValueCollection newValues = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection (Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties["fieldname"]));
```